# how to fix incorrect reference count of DLLs from Wix installer

Tags: dll, wix, reference-counting

I'm using WIX installer and trying to delete the installation of a program.
The problem is that I have an incorrect reference count .

I'll try to be more specific-
I have 2 computers 
on the first one when I install and then uninstall - everything is being deleted (when I enter the register editor - the dlls are deleted)
on the second computer - some of the dlls stay! even when I uninstall the program. when I look at the register editor- their reference count is (1) ..

how can I fix it? I can change it but It's only for this computer... is there a way to change that?
what can \need I add to Wix if I wan't it to update me that not all dlls were deleted?
how can I do that?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just before you uninstall the reference count of that dll, it must be 1.

Yes. You can change the reference count to 1 and you will fix that problem.  Use the modify in your registry editor.

If you want the uninstall to update you that not all dlls were deleted, you need to scan the registry for that particular dll's reference count.  There is more than one way to do that.
I suggest you write a separate utility that you can run after an installation and output the reference count of the particular dll if it exist.